# ngx-slick-carousel infite loop and responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I'm using ngx-slick-carousel to display youtube videos in my project, the first problem is that the carousel is not infinite, when the last video appears, the first one is not next to it, there are just white spaces, when the carousel gets the final video to the end it goes back to the first slide, I want the carousel to display the first slide next to the final so it doesn't make the animation to go back to the first slide.

The second problem is the responsive display, I put the responsive code in my TS file but seems that the youtube video is not responding to this, also i tried to use bootstrap grid to achieve this but didnt work, any advice on this problems?

**HTML file**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="slick-wrapper">
      <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config] = "slideConfig" (init)="slickInit($event)" (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <youtube-player 
              videoId= {{slide.videoId}}
              suggestedQuality="default" 
              [height]="" 
              [width]="" 
              [startSeconds]="0"
              [endSeconds]="">
            </youtube-player>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </ngx-slick-carousel>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videos',
  templateUrl: './videos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videos.component.css']
})
export class VideosComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  }

  slides = [
    {videoId: "rf8vM_X1g9U"},
    {videoId: "3xq7z7WBOGU"},
    {videoId: "9PBeqHEopLs"},
    {videoId: "1jeHyrRskdk"},
    {videoId: "KauOtgNuzQQ"}
  ];

  slideConfig = {
    "slidesToShow": 3, 
    "slidesToScroll": 1, 
    "autoplay": true, 
    "autoplaySpeed": 3000,
    "infinite": true,
    "responsive": [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  slickInit(e: any) {
    console.log('slick initialized');
  }

  breakpoint(e: any) {
    console.log('breakpoint');
  }

}
```

**I only have this in my css**

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
  color: black!important;
}
```

I'm using `youTube-player Module` to display the youTube videos and using the `*ngFor` to get the videos ID

Answer (score 0):

I endup using another carousel, I'll leave the code in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70779897/animation-slide-in-multi-item-carousel-with-youtube-videos-bootstrap-5-and-angul)

It seems that the infinite loop is a bug, theres an [issue](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1207) of this in github